# Gridster.js with 100% width

Tags: gridster

Is it possible to make gridster.js have 100% width for the canvas (not the grid elements but the canvas itself. This would have to update on resize. I saw the width: "auto" property but I'm not sure if it's doing anything in my fiddle, but in any case it doesnt work as desired.

http://jsfiddle.net/JQPurfect/xP8Ks/1/light/

```
$(function(){
    var options = {
      widget_base_dimensions: [100, 120],
      widget_margins: [5, 5],
        //width: 'auto',
      draggable: {
        handle: 'header'
      }
    };
    $(".gridster ul").gridster(options);


      $(window).resize(function() {
            $(".gridster ul").gridster(options);
      });

});
```

Comment: I don't understand. What exactly do you want to have 100% width and of what? Do you want Gridster to automatically calculate widget base width so div.gridster would be fully used?

Comment: yeah, basically. sorry if it was poorly phrased.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean besides setting it yourself?

```
$(".gridster ul").gridster(options).width("auto");
```